# ¿Convertir a mayúscula el primer caracter «posible» (incluyendo vocales acentuadas), ignorando caracteres «inconvertibles» como símbolos o números?

Tags: php, string

Yo necesito mostrar siempre la primera letra de una cadena en mayúscula, pero quisiera que vaya ignorando los caracteres *«inconvertibles»* <sup>1</sup> a mayúscula hasta convertir el primer caracter *«posible»* <sup>2</sup>.

Por ejemplo:

- `¿hola mundo?` ........................que determine que `h` es el primer caracter a convertir
- `á es una vocal acentuada`.... que convierta `À`
- `10 elementos` .........................que determine que `e`es el primer caracter a convertir
- `hola mundo` ...........................que determine que `h` es el primer caracter a convertir (funcionamiento normal)
- y así por el estilo, todas las futuras posibles ocurrencias.

Para estos fines el Manual dice que la función indicada es `ucfirst`, pero no funciona en los casos expuestos:

```
$str="¿hola mundo?";
echo ucfirst($str);
```

Obtengo esto:

```
¿hola mundo?
```

El resultado deseado sería:

- `¿Hola mundo?`
- `Á es una vocal acentuada`
- `10 Elementos`

**¿Hay alguna forma de lograr eso con `ucfirst` u otra función?**

---

<sup>1</sup> Entiéndase por *caracter inconvertible* cualquier número, símbolo, espacio en blanco y todos esos que son indiferentes a eso que se llama mayúscula/minúscula :)

<sup>2</sup> Entiéndase por *caracter posible* cualquier letra del alfabeto, consonante o vocal (acentuada o no), incluyendo la letra `ñ`.

Comment: Nada que discutir a la pregunta. Me genera la duda la frase Á es una... porque si deberia ir acentuada y en mayusculas, y la e no deberia.. pero lo podrias preguntar tranquilamente en el sitio de lenguaje español que te van a contestar con gusto.

Comment: @gbianchi ¿dices que hay alguna regla que indica que la `É` no se acentúa?  No entendí bien tu comentario.

Comment: Perdona. Lo que quise decir es que la frase a es una ... esta bien puesta la mayuscula. Va solo con la a en mayuscula y con el acento.

Comment: @gbianchi las vocales acentuadas no las convierte a mayúscula, las muestra así cuando aplico `ucfirst`: `á es una vocal acentuada`.

Comment: Ahhh perfecto. Entonces no me quedo claro en la pregunta. Disculpas nuevamente!

Comment: que tal si generas un array con todas la letras que sabemos que si es posibles convertir, y las evaluas cada una con dividiendo la cadena, y si es posible que ejecute `ucfirst`, (bueno es solo una idea) (><)

Answer (score 5):

La forma mas fácil que he encontrado es convertir la cadena completamente a minúscualas y a mayúsculas e ir comparando carácter a carácter, de esta forma podemos cubrir todos los casos expuestos con unas pocas líneas. Se han utilizado las funciones [multibyte `mb_`](http://php.net/manual/es/ref.mbstring.php) para dar cobertura a cualquier carácter extraño.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
function first(string $cadena) {
    // salida
    $out = '';
    // obtenemos la longitud
    $len = mb_strlen($cadena, 'UTF-8');
    // cadena en minúsculas
    $min = mb_convert_case($cadena,  MB_CASE_LOWER);
    // cadena en mayúsculas
    $mas = mb_convert_case($cadena,  MB_CASE_UPPER);

    //comparamos carácter a carácter
    for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        // si son iguales añadimos a la salida y continuamos
        if(mb_substr($min, $i, 1, 'UTF-8')==mb_substr($mas, $i, 1, 'UTF-8')){
            $out .= mb_substr($cadena, $i, 1, 'UTF-8');
            continue;
        }
        // si no son iguales extraemos el carácter en mayúscula
        $out .= mb_substr($mas, $i, 1, 'UTF-8');
        // extraemos el resto de la cadena
        $out .= mb_substr($cadena, $i+1, NULL, 'UTF-8');
        // salimos del bucle
        break;
    }
    return $out;
}


echo first('¿hola mundo?').'<br>';
echo first('á es una vocal acentuada').'<br>';
echo first('10 elementos').'<br>';
echo first('hola mundo').'<br>';
echo first('ñññññ').'<br>';
echo first('¡hola mundo!').'<br>';
?>
```

Resultado:

```
¿Hola mundo?
Á es una vocal acentuada
10 Elementos
Hola mundo
Ñññññ
¡Hola mundo!
```

> **string first(string $cadena)**
>     Convierte el primer carácter "convertible" de una cadena a mayúscula, si el primer carácter "convertible" ya esta en mayúscula, no realiza ningún cambio.

---

Con una pequeña modificación a la función, podríamos crear una recursividad, para poder conseguir el mismo efecto sobre cada palabra, es decir, convertir a mayúsculas la primera letra de cada palabra.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
function first(string $cadena, $word=false) {
    // salida
    $out = '';

    // recursividad por palabra
    if($word){
        // dividimos por espacios y recorremos
        foreach(mb_split(' ', $cadena) as $value){
            $out .= first($value.' ');
        }
        return rtrim($out);
    }

    // obtenemos la longitud
    $len = mb_strlen($cadena, 'UTF-8');
    // cadena en minúsculas
    $min = mb_convert_case($cadena,  MB_CASE_LOWER);
    // cadena en mayúsculas
    $mas = mb_convert_case($cadena,  MB_CASE_UPPER);
    //comparamos carácter a carácter
    for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        // si son iguales añadimos a la salida yield continuamos
        if(mb_substr($min, $i, 1, 'UTF-8')==mb_substr($mas, $i, 1, 'UTF-8')){
            $out .= mb_substr($cadena, $i, 1, 'UTF-8');
            continue;
        }
        // si no son iguales estraemos el carácter en mayuscuala
        $out .= mb_substr($mas, $i, 1, 'UTF-8');
        // estraemos el resto de la cadena
        $out .= mb_substr($cadena, $i+1, NULL, 'UTF-8');
        // salimos del bucle
        break;
    }
    return $out;
}


echo first('¿hola? ¿mundo?', true).'<br>';
echo first('¿á es una vocal acentuada?', true).'<br>';
echo first('¡10 Elementos!', true).'<br>';
echo first('hola mundo', true).'<br>';
echo first('-ñññ -íñ', true).'<br>';
echo first('¡hola mundo!', true).'<br>';
echo first('ππ ςς ₫ ææ', true).'<br>';
?>
```

Resultado:

```
¿Hola? ¿Mundo?
¿Á Es Una Vocal Acentuada?
¡10 Elementos!
Hola Mundo
-Ñññ -Íñ
¡Hola Mundo!
Ππ Σς ₫ Ææ
```

> **string first(string $cadena[, bool $word = false])**
>     Convierte el primer carácter "convertible" de una cadena a mayúscula, si el primer carácter "convertible" ya esta en mayúscula, no realiza ningún cambio. Si establecemos el segundo parámetro como TRUE convierte el primer carácter "convertible" de cada palabra en mayúsula. Si el primer carácter "convertible" ya esta en mayúscula, no realiza ningún cambio.

Comment: Solo como advertencia para el usuario, para usar las funciones "mb_" debe estar habilitado en php.ini la extensión "mbstring".

Comment: @aeportugal cierto, buen apunte. para instalarlas en linux se puede utilizar por ejemplo `sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring`

Answer (score 3):

Solo pude resolver 3 de tus 4 casos, revisando la documentación sobre `ucfirst`, puede elaborar la siguiente funcion:

```
    function ucfirsts($str,$a_char = array("¿","¡","'",'"',"-",".")){    

        $string = strtolower($str);
        foreach ($a_char as $temp){
            $pos = strpos(utf8_encode($string),$temp);
            if ($pos==true){                
                $mend = '';
                $a_split = explode($temp,$string);
                foreach ($a_split as $temp2){
                    $mend .=  ucfirst($temp2).$temp;                    
                }
                $string = substr($mend,0,-2);

            }else{
                $string = mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($string, 0, 1)).mb_substr($string, 1);
            }
        }
        return $string;
    }
    echo ucfirsts('¿hola mundo?').'<br>';
    echo ucfirsts('á es una vocal acentuada').'<br>';
    echo ucfirsts('hola mundo');
```

Espero haya sido de ayuda o que por lo menos te pueda servir de guía para lograr el resultado que deseas.

Answer (score 3):

Propongo realizarlo con una función recursiva que compare los caracteres con expresiones regulares. Con esto logré resolver los 4 ejemplos y otros como por ejemplo poner muchos caracteres especiales al principio.

```
function cap_string($string, $new_string = ''){

    //Si la cadena comienza con mayúscula, la devuelve sin modificar
    if(preg_match("/^[A-Z]/",$string) AND empty($newstring)):
        return $string;

    //Si es una letra en minúscula usa ucfirst()
    elseif(preg_match("/^[a-z]/",$string)):
        $new_string = $new_string.ucfirst($string);

    //Si es una vocal con acento o ñ usa la función mb_strtoupper()
    elseif(preg_match("/^[áéíóúñ]/",$string)):
        $count = strlen ($string);
        $rest = substr($string, -($count-2));
        $l = mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($string, 0, 1));
        $new_string .= $l.$rest;

    //Si no coincide guarda el caracter y vuelve a comenzar la función con la letra siguiente
    else:
        $count = strlen ($string);
        $new_string .= substr($string, 0, 1);
        $rest = substr($string, -($count-1));
        return cap_string($rest, $new_string);
    endif;

    return $new_string;
}

echo cap_string('¿hola mundo?');
//¿Hola mundo?

echo cap_string('á es una vocal acentuada');
//Á es una vocal acentuada

echo cap_string('10 elementos');
//10 Elementos

echo cap_string('hola mundo');
//Hola mundo
```

Espero que te sirva.

Saludos!

Comment: Al igual que las otras respuestas, falla cuando abre un signo de admiración "¡", posiblemente ese signo deba tratarse diferente, pero sin considerar eso, me gusta más este código.

Answer (score 2):

Como dice en el manual [`ucfirst`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.ucfirst.php):

> Nótese que 'alfabético' se determina por la localización actual. Por ejemplo, los caracteres de localización "C" como [umlaut](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umlaut)-a (ä) no serán convertidos.

Por tal motivo es necesario recurrir al uso de las funciones provistas por [`mbstring`](http://php.net/manual/es/intro.mbstring.php):

> `mbstring` proporciona funciones específicas para cadenas de texto multibyte que ayudan a tratar codificaciones multibyte en PHP. Además, `mbstring` controla la conversión de la codificación de caracteres entre los posibles esquemas de codificación. `mbstring` está diseñada para manejar codificaciones basadas en Unicode, tales como UTF-8 y UCS-2

#### Solución:

Podemos crear una `RegExp` (*según el criterio que tengamos*) para encontrar la primer "letra" y convertir solo esta a mayúscula.

```
function ucfirstLetter($string) {
    // Flag u para activar UTF8 y modo PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE para que devuelva la posicion de la cadena
    preg_match('/[^a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ]*([a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ]){1}.*/u', $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    // Si no tiene letras
    if (empty($matches)) { return $string; }
    // Posicion de la primer letra
    $pos = $matches[count($matches) - 1][1];
    // Fix posicion cadena multibyte
    $firsPart = mb_substr($string, 0, $pos);
    $pos -= strlen($firsPart) - mb_strlen($firsPart);
    // Obtenemos y convertimos la primer letra a mayuscula
    $letter = mb_convert_case(mb_substr($string, $pos, 1), MB_CASE_UPPER);
    // Generamos nuevamente la cadena
    return mb_substr($string, 0, $pos) . $letter . mb_substr($string, $pos + 1);
}
```

Resultados:

```
¿Hola mundo?
Á es una vocal acentuada
10 Elementos
Hola mundo
```

Answer (score 0):

leyendo lo que necesitas, me acabo de inventar este algoritmo con una funcion que evalua las cadenas y que quizas sea lo que necesites o por lo menos te de una idea.

```
function cambiar($cadena)
{
    //dividimos la cadena
    $caracter = explode("", $cadena);
    //letras permitidas
    $permitidas= array(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,ñ,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,á,é,í,ó,ú);
    //el dolor de cabeza de las acentudas
    $acentuadas = array(á,é,í,ó,ú);

    $resultado='';
    //empezamos a recorrer la cadena
    for ($j=0; $j < count($caracter) ; $j++) { 
        //recorremos las letras permitidas
        for ($r=0; $r < count($permitidas); $r++) { 
            //comparamos si coincid el caracte con una de las permitidas
            if ($caracter[$j] == $permitidas[$r]) {
                //recorremos las acentudas acentuada
                for ($s=0; $s < count($acentuadas); $s++) { 
                    //comparamos si coincide con alguna acentuada
                    if ($caracter[$j] == $acentuadas[$s]) {
                        //con el switch asinamos el nuevo valor
                        switch ($caracter[$j]) {
                            case 'value':
                                $caracter[$j] = 'Á';
                                break;
                            case 'value':
                                $caracter[$j] = 'É';
                                break;
                            case 'value':
                                $caracter[$j] = 'Í';
                                break;
                            case 'value':
                                $caracter[$j] = 'Ó';
                                break;
                            case 'value':
                                $caracter[$j] = 'Ú';
                                break;
                        }
                        //unimos de nuevo la cadena
                        $resultado= implode("", $caracter);
                        //terminamos el ciclo
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                        //si no es una acentuada entonces le asinamos el valor en mayuscula
                        $caracter[$j] = strtoupper($permitidas[$r]);
                        //unimos la cadena
                        $resultado= implode("", $caracter);
                        //terminamos el ciclo
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
    //retornamos el valor
    return $resultado;
}
```

espero sea lo que necesitas, o bueno te sirva de algo xD...

Answer (score 0):

En php existen métodos adicionales empezados por `mb` para especificar una codificación, no existe un método directo como tal para `ucfirst`, pero en base a esta respuesta se puede construir
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517947/ucfirst-function-for-multibyte-character-encodings

Sin embargo este no hace lo que quieres de si por ejemplo haya un signo de interrogación transforme la primera letra, pero se puede modificar o extender.

```
echo mb_ucfirst('¿á que hora?','utf-8');
function mb_ucfirst($string, $encoding)
{
    $strlen = mb_strlen($string, $encoding);
    $firstPosition = mb_first_letter($string, $encoding);
    echo $firstPosition."<br>";
    $before = mb_substr($string, 0, $firstPosition, $encoding);
    $firstChar = mb_substr($string, $firstPosition, $firstPosition + 1, $encoding);
    $then = mb_substr($string, $firstPosition + 1, $strlen - 1, $encoding);
    return $before.mb_strtoupper($firstChar, $encoding) . $then;
}

function mb_first_letter($string, $encoding) {
    preg_match('/[A-zÁ-ú]/u', $string, $matches);
    return mb_stripos($string,mb_convert_encoding($matches[0], $encoding), 0, $encoding) ?? 0;
}
```

El único problema ahí, es que la expresión regular quedó un poco harcodeada para el encoding utf8, pero esta se podría pasar como parámetro y cambiarla, ya no lo hice por simplicidad, pero como podrás ver sería bastante sencillo