# Colocar la primera letra de cada palabra en mayuscula de un string

Tags: php

Quiero colocar la primera letra de cada palabra en mayúsculas obviando los conectores

por ejemplo:

```
   $str= mb_convert_case("PLATA JUGUETES Y ÚTILES", MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");
```

Lo que espero obtener es : Plata Juguetes y Útiles

Comment: Javier, [aquí se dieron varias respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/194132/29967) que te pueden servir. Mi requerimiento era más exigente y todavía no me he podido decidir por una respuesta correcta. Sin embargo, hay buenísimas respuestas en la pregunta.

Comment: ¿El problema que tienes es que "Y" también lo convierte? ya que veo que el ejemplo que muestras convertiría la cadena a "Plata Juguetes Y Útiles".

Comment: Lo que espero obtener es : Plata Juguetes **y** Útiles, pero el problema es que los conectores como la( Y O De ) los necesito en minuscula.

Comment: OK @javier las palabras con longitud de 2 carácteres (y, o, de) no deseas convertirlas a mayúscula , sería "Plata Juguetes y Útiles", he agregado respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

En este caso usar se puede usar algún método para convertir las primeras letras de cada palabra a mayúscula pero necesitas tener "y" en minúscula.

Puedes usar [ucwords()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.ucwords.php) para las palabras que tengan una palabra con longitud mayor a 2 ("PLATA", "JUGUETES", "ÚTILES")y para las que no cumplen esta condición convertirlas a minúscula ("Y", "O", "DE"):

```
$str = mb_convert_case("PLATA JUGUETES Y ÚTILES", MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");

$words = explode(" ", $str);
$result = "";

foreach ($words as $w) {
    if(strlen($w) > 2){
        $result.=ucwords(strtolower($w)).' ';
    }else{
        $result.=strtolower($w).' ';
    }

}

echo $result;
```

de esta forma obtendrías como salida:

```
Plata Juguetes y Útiles
```

Puedes ver la <kbd>[demostración en linea](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5b85f22e9e4270a4768f6e53d8d6f53d4f105470)</kbd>

---

Esto también funciona en el caso de palabras acentuadas en minúscula como :

```
 $str= mb_convert_case("plata juguetes y útiles", MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");
```

---

Este es otro ejemplo:

```
$str= mb_convert_case("PLATA JUGUETES Y ÚTILES DE JAVIER o jorgesys", MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");
```

<kbd>[Demostración en línea](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9df24efd6ed0545e8e7d97cf5ffe600eae5f3875)</kbd>

tendrías como valor resultante:

```
Plata Juguetes y Útiles de Javier o Jorgesys
```

Comment: Prueba: "plata juguetes y útiles"... no te va a funcionar

Comment: También funciona para "plata juguetes y útiles". \m/

Comment: ahora si... [antes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/214079/3) no.... :p

Comment: Veo que me comentas antes de terminar mi respuesta, por ejemplo escribí que podía usar "ucwords()"  y al instante comentaste no funcionaba, espera a que terminé de escribir mi respuesta, ahora cumple todas las condiciones.

Comment: y cuando se que haz terminado tu respuesta???

Comment: Hay otra respuestas que puedes revisar, también ahí puedes realizar sugerencias, por lo pronto ya he terminado \m/.

Answer (score 1):

En esta función que he creado, mira si la cadena tiene más de 2 caracteres si es así la primera letra será en mayúscula:

```
echo capitalize("PLATA JUGUETES Y ÚTILES");

function capitalize($str, $encoding = 'UTF-8') {

    $str = mb_strtolower($str, $encoding);

    // Creamos un array de la cádena
    $arrStr = explode(' ', $str);

    $pushArray = [];

    foreach( $arrStr as $value ) {

        // Si el string tiene más que 1 character lo convertimos a mayúscula
        if ( mb_strlen($value, $encoding) > 1 ) {

            $pushArray[] = mb_convert_case($value, MB_CASE_TITLE, $encoding);
        }
        else {
            $pushArray[] = $value;
        }
    }

    // Devolvemos el string completo
    return implode(' ', $pushArray); // Plata Juguetes y Útiles
}
```

<kbd>[**Ver Demo Online**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6156dc718c7383d5dceae712216afe7ae369ec40)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Propongo una respuesta que no es mía, la obtuve de una [respuesta de Antonio Max en SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17817669/4987172). La adapté ya que dices que necesitas que los conectores sean los únicos que no se conviertan a mayusculas. En el parametro `$exceptions` pones las palabras que no deseas convertir. Yo puse todas las preposiciones, pero se pueden agregar más palabras.

```
<?php

$s = 'PLATA JUGUETES Y ÚTILES PLATA, Juguetes y útiles';
$v = titleCase($s);
echo $v."";

function titleCase($string, $delimiters = array(" ", "-", ".", "'", "O'", "Mc"), $exceptions = array("a","ante","bajo","cabe","con","contra","de","desde","en","entre","hacia","hasta","para","por","según","sin","so","sobre","tras","y"))
{
    /*
     * Exceptions en minusculas son las palabras que no deseas convertir
     * Exceptions en mayusculas son las palabras que no deseas convertir a title case
     *   pero deben ser converidas a mayusculas, e.g.:
     *   king henry viii o king henry Viii deben ser King Henry VIII
     */
    $string = mb_convert_case($string, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");
    foreach ($delimiters as $dlnr => $delimiter) {
        $words = explode($delimiter, $string);
        $newwords = array();
        foreach ($words as $wordnr => $word) {
            if (in_array(mb_strtoupper($word, "UTF-8"), $exceptions)) {
                // check exceptions list for any words that should be in upper case
                $word = mb_strtoupper($word, "UTF-8");
            } elseif (in_array(mb_strtolower($word, "UTF-8"), $exceptions)) {
                // check exceptions list for any words that should be in upper case
                $word = mb_strtolower($word, "UTF-8");
            } elseif (!in_array($word, $exceptions)) {
                // convert to uppercase (non-utf8 only)
                $word = ucfirst($word);
            }
            array_push($newwords, $word);
        }
        $string = join($delimiter, $newwords);
   }//foreach
   return $string;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Es simple, tan solo debes usar la función ucwords() — Que convierte a mayúsculas el primer caracter de cada palabra de una cadena

https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ucwords.php

```
ucwords('plata juguetes y útiles');
// imprimirá cada palabra con la primera mayúscula
```

Comment: Ya fue planteada esa opción en una respuesta anterior y el método por sí solo no cumple con lo esperado por el OP. Si ejecuto `ucwords('plata juguetes y útiles')` me devolverá `Plata Juguetes Y Útiles`, pero el OP espera la `y` en minúscula.